# How to accept only specific file from the change set

Tags: rational-team-concert

In SCM, I have created a change set with multiple files and I delivered the change set to the team leader. Team leader wants to get only 2-3 files from the delivered change set. Is there a way to accept only particular files from the change set?

Regards,
Kiran

Comment: Would https://jazz.net/forum/questions/125536/how-load-only-one-file-within-a-component-with-scm-load help?